# Count a specific word using a Function ans a Sub

Tags: vb.net

In VB.net, I want to make a counting program using a Function and a Sub.

There is a textbox to input a date and a button to exercise the programme in Form1.

I have a txt file which was extracted from MS-Excel with sequential date of time at its column A.

And from that txt file, I want to count the number of date(Actually string) such as "18-Jun-12".

The answer showing the count should be in the format of msgbox in the Sub.

I really have no idea how to link a Function and a Sub using variable, because I am just beginner.

Any help will be gratefully accepted.

Comment: If the user must enter a date you could use a `DateTimePicker` control instead. Apart from that, what kind of file is that, how are the columns separated from each other(what's the delimiter)?

Comment: The delimiter is ",".

Comment: What if the column itself contains a comma? You should use a different delimiter.

Comment: You should split your problem into smaller/simpler problems. That way you can focus on one part at a time instead of being confused at the whole situation. Can you open/read a file? Parse a file? Search a string? Count? Get the information from a textbox? Display the result? ...

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are delimited by comma you must be careful since the field itself could contain a comma. Then you cannot differentiate between the value and the delimiter. You either could enclose the fields with quotes to mask them. But then you should use an [available CSV parser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) anyway.

If the values never contain comma and you want a simple solution use `File.ReadLines` or `File.ReadAllLines` to read the lines and `String.Split` to get all fields per line.

Here's a simple approach using a little bit of LINQ to count all lines which contain the searched date (as string):

```
Dim linesWithThatDate = From line in File.ReadLines("Path to File")
                        Where line.Split(","c)(0).Trim() = "18-Jun-12" 
Dim count = linesWithThatDate.Count()
```

As an aside, if the user must enter a date you could use a `DateTimePicker` control instead. Then you should also use `Date.Parse(line.Split(","c)(0).Trim())` or `Date.TryParse` to get a real date.